# facebook graph api get posts by ids

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pull a small group of feed/post objects from Facebook Graph API from an array of post ids.

```
string[] postids = {1234,1235,1236}
```

Could someone kindly show me the query string that request the posts?

I've tried using (but I know it's not correct)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?ids=1234,1235,1236
```

No luck

Comment: Might look something like this 
https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?ids=1234,1235,1236

Comment: `graph.facebook.com/?ids=1234,1235,1236`

Comment: I've encountered a problem, if I am querying based on a user this command returns no results. Here is an example of my query

https://graph.facebook.com?ids=..._754506941395065,..._754318771413882,..._753120678200358&fields=message,story,id,created_time,attachments,comments,likes&access_token=...

Comment: Then you either don’t have permission from that user to read their posts, or you do not have valid post ids.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the api version number in your Get request. For example, your URL should look like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?ids=1234,1235,1236
```

Comment: Thanks Hanane.  These suggestions appear to be working to a degree.  I have a few things to consider but, this is an excellent start.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.  I was pulling from the feed end point in one query and the ids were different based on the query.